# malloc works with int but not with strings

Tags: c, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, assignment-operator

Im a very new to C language. Im trying to learn about to memory allocation with the next examples.

If I allocate memory for a integer like this:

```c
int* pint = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    if (pint == NULL) {
        printf("NULL pointer!");
    } else {
        *pint = 5;
        printf("el valor es: %d", *pint);
        free(pint);
    }
```

This show perfectly the number 5 and the memory is liberated correctly

But If I try to do the same with a string like this:

```c
char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);

    if (string == NULL) {
        printf("NULL pointer!");
    } else {
        *string = "Hello World!";
        printf("%s", *string);
        free(string);
    }
```

Why is that happening and how I can fix it?

thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Sorry I forgot to show the error that c compiler throws, my bad.

The error is:

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Sorry for my bad english, it isn't my native language. Thanks again.

Comment: Hint: `*string = "Hello World!";` is *not* how you do it. See: `strcpy()`.

Comment: Tip: You'll need to brush up on what is and isn't copyable via `*` dereferencing. `int*` is a trivial copy, and `char*` would work, if you were copying a *single `char`*.

Comment: More hints: "Hello World!" doesn't fit in 2 bytes

Comment: Doing `*string` returns the _first_ `char` of `string`, but `printf` needs a `char *` for `%s`. So, you want: `printf("%s",string);` But, your `malloc` only allocates space for _one_ byte--not enough space for a string which needs space for the EOS (0x00) terminator. The TL;DR is: forego the `malloc` and change `*string = "Hello World!"` --> `string = strdup("Hello World!");`

Comment: You can/should look up the documentation for `strdup`. But, the code you'll need is something akin to it. Here's a simple example: `char * strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != NULL) memcpy(dup,str,len); return dup; }`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ to be exactly `1` - always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this memory allocation

```
char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
```

does not make sense.

There are allocated only 2 bytes because `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

If you want to allocate an array that will store the string `"Hello World!"` then you should write for example

```
char *string = malloc( sizeof( "Hello World!" ) );
```

In this statement

```
*string = "Hello World!";
```

the pointer `string` is dereferenced. So the left side operand of the assignment statement (the expression `*string` is equivalent to the expression `string[0]`) has the type `char` while the right side operand has the type `char[13]` (string literals have types of character arrays) that is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the string literal of the type `char *`.

So in this assignment statement you are trying to assign a pointer to a character. The compiler should issue a message for this statement because there is no implicit conversion from pointers to characters.

Also in this call of printf

```
printf("%s", *string);
```

you are trying to output a single character `*string` as a whole string using the conversion specifier `%s` that results in undefined behavior.

Instead of this statement

```
*string = "Hello World!";
```

you could write for example

```
string = "Hello World!";
```

That is now the pointer `string` points to the string literal. And if you will write

```
printf("%s", string);
```

then indeed the string literal will be outputted.

But that leads to a memory leak because the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost in this case.

To copy the content of the string literal you should use standard string function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
char *string = malloc( sizeof( "Hello World!" ) );
if ( string != NULL ) 
{
    strcpy( string, "Hello World!" );
    printf( "%s\n", string ); // or just puts( string );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement;

```
char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
```

allocates memory for only `2` bytes.

---

Then:

```
*string = "Hello World!";
```

doesn't copy the string literal `"Hello World!` to `string`.

The C standard library provides `strcpy` to copy two strings. You could also use POSIX's `strdup`.

---

### Incorrect argument to `printf`:

```
printf("%s", *string);
```

`%s` format specifier expects a `char *`, `*string` produces a `char`.

Change it to:

```
printf("%s", string);
```

---

*Aside*: Casting the result of `malloc` and family is redundant and could hide a bug. These functions return a `void *` which is automatically promoted to the correct type.